# Pivot Table adding information each day

Tags: google-sheets, transpose, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I have this Google Sheet "Sheet1"

```
Date         Team1  Team2  Team3  Team4 
2019-03-18   x      y      x      z
2019-03-19   y      0      x      x
2019-03-20   y      y      0      y
```

with a lot of rows. Each day I aggregate a new row.

I want to make another Sheet ("Sheet2") and reorder this information like this:

```
Date        Teams  Counts

2019-03-18  Team1  x
2019-03-18  Team2  y
2019-03-18  Team3  x
2019-03-18  Team4  z
2019-03-19  Team1  y
2019-03-19  Team3  x
2019-03-19  Team4  x
2019-03-20  Team1  y
2019-03-20  Team2  y
2019-03-20  Team4  y
etc.
```

How Can I do it? I need to automate this process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do it like this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IF(B1:E<>"", "♦"&A1:A&"♣"&B1:E, )),,999^99)),,999^99), "♦")), "♣"))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thanks @player0, It is very helpful, however the dates does not match when I apply this solution. I explain better my question now  by editing it "date1", "date2", "date3" are actually dates and not strings. Also is it possible to copy the name of the teams as in my edited question? Thanks

Comment: I see, Now the date column is correctly formatted. How can I repeat the Team name together with the date on a third column?
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Id10ZtfAqrW5zcbss9tF9vKI9ir14Cm7J-2W_xHcyGM/edit?usp=sharing